# Odoo error after installing xls report

Tags: webkit, odoo-8, xls

I added xls engine and webkit addons. I am using Windows 2008 server. When I try to print ledger reports, it gives the following error:

```
Required report does not exist: account.account_report_general_ledger_xls

<type 'exceptions.Exception'>,Required report does not exist: account.account_report_general_ledger_xls,<traceback object at 0x1030CE40
```

Can any one guide me what im doing wrong? I did the same steps on another windows 7 server, its not giving me any error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that odoo can't find the report. Did you try an update all? Or take a look and try to find the report in database.